# Identify regions where $\sin(e^x)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks to differentiate $\sin(e^x)$ and then determine where it is analytic.

I know how to differentiate it to get $f'(z) = e^z \cos(e^z)$ but I am unsure how to find where it is analytic. Do I need to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Answer (score 1):

No. Just use the facts that $\sin z$ and $e^z$ are analytic and composition of analytic functions remains analytic.

Comment: In general you would have to watch out for points where $e^z \cos(e^z)$ does not exist.  But for this problem there are no such points.

Comment: Let me phrase what you've written a bit differently: we have to watch out for such $z_0$ that $e^z$ is not analytic in $z = z_0$ and for such $z_0$ that $\sin w$ is not analytic in $w = e^{z_0}$.

Comment: got it, thanks!